# How to GetClipboardData?

Tags: python

I use python to simulate the ctrl+A and ctrl+C operation.But the output is what I copied before run the code,could someone tell me why?

```
import win32clipboard as w  
import win32con 
import win32api
import win32gui
import time 

win32api.SetCursorPos([500,300])
win32api.keybd_event(17,0,0,0) #ctrl键位码是17
win32api.keybd_event(65,0,0,0) #A键位码是86
win32api.keybd_event(65,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0) #释放按键
win32api.keybd_event(67,0,0,0) #c键位码是67
win32api.keybd_event(67,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0) #释放按键
win32api.keybd_event(17,0,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0)
w.OpenClipboard()
d = w.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_UNICODETEXT)   
w.EmptyClipboard()
w.CloseClipboard() 
print d
```

Comment: Have you verified that these keyboard events are correctly generated? Does the target application get focused?

Comment: I think they are correctly generated,because when I press ctrl+V  after running the code,I got the right content. I thought maybe there is something wrong with the handle which is of the window openning the cilpboard,so I modified  w.OpenClipboard()  to w.OpenClipboard(w.GetClipboardOwner()),but it still didn't work.